# How to link NodeJs and Angular JS (without any frameworks such as Express)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

I have Angular JS routing set as following:

```
function routing($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : '/index.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
MODULE.config(routing);
```

In my Node server, how do I go to the home page (without Express or any framework). I have searched all around the internet but most of the examples use frameworks such as Express.

Comment: Where does 'without Express or any framework' requirement come from? It makes no sense, unless this is a homework (and homeworks are offtopic on SO). The reason why Express exists is because it allows to do simple tasks like serving static files relatively easily. It isn't clear what the question is about. What 'go to the home page' is?

Answer (score -1):

put all your files in src folders all files in to public folder and give its path to server.

```
// Routing
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

and you can use your angular files in node js